# How to capture mouse movements C# form application?

Tags: c#, forms

How to capture mouse movements C# form application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a snippet:

```
Point mouseLocation;

public Form1( )
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
}

void Form1_MouseMove(object sender , MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseLocation = e.Location;
}
```

@AdriannStander gives 3 excellent links for research -- I simply like writing code snippets   ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one works for ALL controls within the form. NOT just the form itself!

```
    ....
InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
                {
                    ctrl.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(globalMouseMove);
                }
    ....

     private void globalMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                //TODO
            }
```